# Pandas replace months names within dataframe values

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have dataset where months are like 'January', 'February' etc.
For example '23:12 25 April 2016'

The goal is to transform it into '23:12 25 4 2016' using .replace() for the whole dataframe.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

UDP. Forgot the main problem: this example has months in english, originally I have them in other language so I need unicode replacement first to `to_datetime`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) for reformating `dates` in column `date`:

```
print df
                  date
0  23:12 25 April 2016

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
print df

                 date
0 2016-04-25 23:12:00
```

Another solution is add parameter [`format`](http://strftime.org/):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%H:%M %d %B %Y")
print df
                 date
0 2016-04-25 23:12:00
```

If names of `months` are Russian use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [u'23:12 25 январь 2016']})

d = {u'январь':'January', u'февраль':'February', u'март':'March'}

df['date'] = df['date'].replace(d, regex=True)

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format="%H:%M %d %B %Y")
print df
                 date
0 2016-01-25 23:12:00
```

Comment: Thanks, but the biggest problem is that months are unicode (other language), so I need replacement before `to_datetime`

Comment: What kind of language?

Comment: Russian months 'Января', 'Февраля' etc.